# Inheritance of JPA Entities

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa

I have a question.

Lets say I have an Entity Class called BaseEntity. I annotate this class with @Entity as follows.

```
@Entity
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    .....
}
```

If I write another class called Employee that extends BaseEntity as

```
public class Employee extends BaseEntity{
    ....
}
```

and I do not annotate it with @Entity, will my employee class have Entity like behaviour?
What I mean to ask is will it become an Entity because its extending my BaseEntity

Or should I always need to annotate a class with @Entity to get Entity like behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to annotate it as entity. But for your base class you can use `@MappedSuperclass`, so that no table is required for it

Answer (score 1):

You have to annotate it (or mark it in orm.xml) as an Entity ... for all classes that are required to be persistable